# How to access the Tensorflow Graph within py_func?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm trying to call `get_default_graph` from a `py_func`. My code snippet is shown below:

```
def test():
    tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("Variable_1:0")


t = tf.py_func(test, [], tf.float32)
```

I get an error that:

> KeyError: "The name 'Variable_1:0' refers a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'Variable_1', does not exist in the graph."

But I did named a variable named `Variable_1`. My hypothesis is that there are issues with using graph operations in `py_func`.

How do I make the above snippet work?

Answer (score 0):

From the definition and given example of [tf.py_func()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func), you need to pass your inputs and specify the data types of your outputs (if multiple).

Your code will need to be rewritten like this:

```
def test():
    # Do whatever computation and return a variable of type float

inp = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("Variable_1:0")
t = tf.py_func(test, [inp], tf.float32)
```